# Spring conditional property validation

Tags: java, spring, validation

Is it possible to use the spring property validation based on another property value?

I can't use the `@ConditionalOnProperty` because the property is used in a lot of places. I can't just put the `@ConditionalOnProperty` for each bean.

Here is what I have:

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Property1 {
    boolean property2Enabled
}

@ConfigurationProperties
public class Property2 {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    String thisShouldBeValidated;

}
```

In this case the validation for `thisShouldBeValidated` should be applied only if the value of `property2Enabled` is `true`.

Is it possible to do this with some spring annotation?
If I write a custom validation can I somehow get the value of the `property2Enabled` if that?

Answer (score 2):

Try the Spring 4 @Conditional annotation that can be applied to @Bean methods.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition;

@ConfigurationProperties
public class Property1 implements Condition{
    boolean property2Enabled;                 

    @Override
    public boolean matches()
       return property2Enabled;
    }
}
```

thisShouldBeValidated should be applied only if the value of property2Enabled is true. Otherwise its ignored.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition;

public class Property2 {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    String thisShouldBeValidated;

    @Bean
    @Conditional(Property1.class)
    void Property2 yourMethod() {
       system.out.println("whatever"+ thisShouldBeValidated);
    }        
}
```

As you can see, `@Conditional` is given a Class that specifies the condition—in this case, `Property1`.
The class given to `@Conditional` can be any type that implements the **Condition
interface**.

Comment: This solution is similar to the  @ConditionalOnProperty what I can't use.
I need a solution that void Property2 yourMethod() always return the Property2 but without validation if property2Enabled = false